# How to use the `import` feature of ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The spec defines the `import/export` statements, but does not define the method to resolve a module. How does the browsers to resolve a module when use `import` statement? If there is no standard to restrain the actions, how should we do?

Comment: your question is not clear, you want to know how it works internally ?

Comment: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/